# Cocos2d: algorithm to get a shadow following a CCSprite in a realistic way

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, sprite, shadow, light

I am working with Cocos2d 2.0 and no else (no BOX2D etc..). I have a character and added a shadow to it as CCSprite child node. It gives a nice "flying effect" when it moves but unfortunately, when the character rotates also the children do and the shadow child moves in an unrealistic way. See this picture:

[image]

In 3D gaming this would be taken care in the graphic engine with a 3D Matrix and the the position of the light source in the game. However my game is much simpler and does not require any 3D graphics so I need to find a programmatic approximation of this.

To first attempted to ovverride the "setPosition" and "setRotation" methods but did not help much (the shadow doesn't change position).

```
-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    [super setPosition:position];


    CCSprite * shadow = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:belowByOneZFirst];
    if (shadow!=nil) {
        [shadow setPosition:shadowOriginalPosition];
        CCLOG(@"Setting shadow position");
    }

}

-(void) setRotation:(float)rotation
{
    [super setRotation:rotation];
    CCSprite * shadow = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:belowByOneZFirst];
    if (shadow!=nil) {
        [shadow setRotation:0];
        CCLOG(@"Setting shadow rotation");
    }

}
```

I have two possible paths to follow now. One is to make the shadow an indipendent CCSprite (and not add it as child) and the other one is to attempt to ovverride the setters modifying the "SET_DIRTY_RECURSIVELY()" macro (it could check if a child has a specific tag and if so does not apply the change).

The first approach is a bit overcomplicated and the second one sounds ok but still a bit too complex.

Also, just not "changing" the shadow relative position does not solve the matter fully. I should instead write some code to adapt the shadow relative position taking account of the relative position of the Sprite within the screen (say I set my sun to be in the top left corner then the shadow will change shape according to the relative position to the sun).

**Has anyone else had a similar algorithm to implement with Cocos2d and if so are there any common patterns to solve this?**

Comment: tip: add both sprite and shadow (with position offset) as child of a ccnode. Move the node, rotate only the sprite, shadow position is still an offset to sprite position. Problem solved (as far as I understood).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Fantastic, thanks a lot (simply genius). You should copy and paste this as an answer so I could accept it and upvote.

Comment: good, wasn't 100% sure if it'll work for you

Answer (score 0):

tip: add both sprite and shadow (with position offset) as child of a ccnode. Move the node, rotate only the sprite, shadow position is still an offset to sprite position. Problem solved (as far as I understood).